# Compute the least $n$ with $a^n \equiv 1 \pmod{\!b}$? (order computation)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

This is mostly related to doing large modular exponentiation by hand. For example, a problem I was doing was to find the last 3 digits of $7^{9729}$; that is, find $7^{9729}\bmod{1000}$.

Using the simplest concept for Euler's theorem, I found that $7^{400}\equiv 1\pmod{1000}$, since $\varphi(1000)=400$. Using Carmichael's theorem, I found a smaller number, $7^{100}\equiv 1\pmod{1000}$, as $\lambda(1000)=100$. Now, by manually multiplying it out, I found that $7^{20}\equiv 1 \pmod{1000}$, and that is the first $n$ for which that is true, meaning I just need to find $7^9 \bmod{1000}$, making the answer 607.

Is there a way to arrive at this answer without multiplying it out each time for every number I get? For example, could I do something like $13^{12937}\bmod{1000}$ without sitting around modding out multiples of $13^4$? (I know that the first $n$ for 13 would be 100, so no less than using Carmichael's theorem, but I want to know if there are other ways to find numbers lower than those given by Carmichael's theorem)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If $\rm\: gcd(a,10)=1\:$ then order of $\rm\: a\:$ in $\:\mathbb Z/1000 \:$ [must be](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/127118/242) a divisor of $100 = \lambda(1000)$. You can compute the order simply and quickly by computing in order  $\rm a^2, a^4, a^5, a^{10}, a^{20}, a^{25}, a^{50}\:$ by squaring or multiplying previous entries. This requires at most 5 squaring and 2 multiplication operations $\rm (mod\ 1000)$. Obviously the same sort of optimized divisor lattice searching works for any modulus.

Alternatively we can use the following well-known simple order algorithm for groups (based upon the [Order Test](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1188614/242)), from Cohen's book *A Course in Computational Algebraic Number Theory*.
[image]
[This thesis](https://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/38881) is a good reference on order algorithms in generic groups. Here's the abstract:
[image]

Comment: now this is a useful result! so basically, I only have to check for every divisor of $\lambda(n)$?

Comment: Yes, in any group the order of an element divides the order/expt of the group (Lagrange's theorem) - see my post here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4715

Comment: @Eugene: That one's from Cohen's "A Course in Computational Algebraic Number Theory"; a good book, if you can find it in your nearest library.

Answer (score 2):

As I discuss in [my answer to this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3976/on-the-binary-decimal-expansion-of-the-reciprocal-primes), this is a hard quantity to compute in general.  For practical purposes you should use [exponentiation by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) to test the possibilities (and you should definitely use exponentiation by squaring for computing remainders in general; this is how computer algebra systems do it).  Note that using Carmichael's theorem is not trivial, as it requires that you know the prime factorization of $b$.

Comment: most values of $b$ that I would work with would not be too difficult to factorize, but otherwise I agree

Comment: @Eugene Bulkin: but the problem is hard even if b is prime (since one needs to factor b-1).  I just mean that if you are given a large random value of b it isn't trivial to apply Carmichael's theorem to it.

Comment: from what I understood looking up Carmichael's theorem, all that is necessary is the prime factorization of b; $\lambda(p_1^{k_1} p_2^{k_2} \cdots p_n^{k_n})=\mathrm{lcm}(\lambda(p_1^{k_1}),\lambda(p_2^{k_2}),\ldots,\lambda(p_n^{k_n}))$, and the function is simple for any $p^k$.

Comment: @Eugene Bulkin: the possible values of n are the divisors of lambda(b), so not only is it necessary to factor b to compute lambda(b), it is then necessary to factor lambda(b).  This is not hard if b is smooth (e.g. it is a large power of a small prime) but is very hard if b is a random prime, since b-1 is for all intents and purposes a random number.

Comment: that is true. I was mostly learning this for a math contest, so they wouldn't really give us any particularly difficult ones. thanks though!