# What is the period of a^r modulo m?

Tags: number-theory

For $a$, $m$ fixed with $a \lt m$ and $r$ a nonnegative integer, I was wondering what the period of $f(r) = a^r$ mod $m$ was. 
For example, when $a=2, m=7$, we get the sequence 1, 2, 4, 1, 2, 4,... with a period of 3. Because there are at most $m$ values that $f$ takes on, it follows that the function must be periodic. I looked at Euler's theorem, but $\phi(n)$ seems to be some multiple of the period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look-up the concept of  [multiplicative order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_order). You have
$a^{\mathrm{ord}_m(a)}=1$ or $a^{1+\mathrm{ord}_m(a)}=a.$ Accidently the Wiki article even uses your $m=7.$ The order devides $\phi(m)$ and even the [Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) function $\lambda(m)$.

For algorithms to compute the multiplicative order if the prime factorizations of
 $\phi(m)$ or $\lambda(m)$ are known, see my answers to: 
[Algorithms for finding the multiplicative order of an element in a group of integers mod m](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/837489/algorithms-for-finding-the-multiplicative-order-of-an-element-in-a-group-of-inte)
and [algorithm to find the order of $a$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^*$ where $n$ is not prime.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/937100/algorithm-to-find-the-order-of-a-in-mathbbz-n-mathbbz-where-n-is)