# Is this statement true: 1 = 0.99

Tags: calculus, logic, decimal-expansion

Now this question might sound a bit weird to some people, but the situation is this:

Say I have the number $0.999..$ where there is an infinite number of 9's (much like $0.3333..$ with $\frac{1}{3}$). For convenience, let's put a line above the 9's to indicate there is an infinite number of 9's: $0.\overline{99}$ (probably not official notation, but what the heck..).

Now if I see a statement like this $1=0.\overline{99}$, I would think this is not true, at first, through more or less the same logic that $1\neq2$.

But the following confuses me: $\frac{1}{9}=0.\overline{11}$, so If I do this:
$$
\frac{1}{9}\cdot9=\frac{9}{9}=1
$$
And also:
$$
0.\overline{11}\cdot9=0.\overline{99}
$$

That means that $1=0.\overline{99}$, but that doesn't make sense to me, because $1$ and $0.\overline{99}$ look like totally different numbers to me... Am I missing something here or is my above logic just false?

Any clarification would be great :)

Comment: This has been discussed before as I discovered here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98288/the-difference-between-10-and-9-99999-recurring

Comment: The line above the digits is standard notation, and I suspect you already knew this.

Comment: Sorry about the duplicate guys, couldn't find it in the search before..

Comment: Try typing 0.999 into the search box and see what you get.

Comment: @FlybyNight derp...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is correct.

Consider:
$$
\begin{align}
x = 0&.9999\ldots\\
10x = 9&.9999\ldots\\
9x = 9&\\
x = 1&
\end{align}
$$

There is an entire [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.999...) on this with a slew of proofs of various kinds.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is correct. $0.999...$ is just a different way of writing the number $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way that might convince you of its truth:
Let $x=0.999...$
Then $10x=9.999...=9+0.999...=9+x$
Therefore $10x-x=9\implies x=1$

Comment: Another thing to consider is this: "What number could you possibly add to $0.999...$ to get $1$?"